# how to design three button if in same page?

Tags: buttons, design, lean-ux

I have one page there displaying three different action buttons. As per UX guidelines how to display or style this button and more focus able.

If can be three action level :

1. Primary
2. Secondary
3. Third

[image]

Comment: It can also be simplified by just having a Primary action and the rest as Secondary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app can show more than one button in a layout at a time, so a high-emphasis button can be accompanied by medium- and low-emphasis buttons that perform less important actions. When using multiple buttons, ensure the available state of one button doesn’t look like the disabled state of another.

So to answer your question I would say:

[image]